# how to send server and site name to graphite?

Tags: graphite, statsd

this is my /opt/graphite/statsd/local.js

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "127.0.0.1"
, port: 8125
, backends: [ "./backends/graphite", "./backends/repeater" ]
, repeater: [ { host: '10.1.2.16', port: 8125 } ]
, graphite: { legacyNamespace: false, globalPrefix: "testing_server_1" }
, flushInterval: 600
}
```

as you can see that i am sending the server name by setting the globalPrefix as "testing_server_1", and set the legacyNamespace to false, so i get two graph like

```
testing_server_1.counters.core_network_bad_soap.rate
and
testing_server_1.counters.core_network_bad_soap.count
```

but when i don't set legacyNamespace and globalPrefix i get one graph only

```
counters.core_network_bad_soap
```

my question is why it is so and secondly, how to set site name along with server name.

Comment: @MattSelf please suggest something on this.

Answer (score 1):

`Q.  when i don't set legacyNamespace and globalPrefix i get one graph only`

The legacy namespacing sent just a counter. The updated namespace auto-generates `rate` and `count`. Here, `count` is the standard orthodox counter that you're looking for, and `rate` is the number of updates of that counter per unit interval.

`Q. why it is so and secondly, how to set site name along with server name.`

Say you have three servers each running two sites and you want the prefixing to be automated. What you can do is-

1. Make each server send metrics to its local `statsd` instance which prepends the current server name and site name (think of this as $this->server_name) to all the metrics.
2. You can write application-wrappers/libraries that do this. This way, you do not need to have countless `statsd` instances as you scale up. The applications will recieve metrics and dynamically prepend the site/server name and then forward it to the statsd.